# UWP MediaPlayerElement stream timeout

Tags: c#, uwp, timeout, media-player, uwp-xaml

I'm using the MediaPlay control in my app and am setting radio streams like so:

```
Player.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri(finalurl));
```

I'm registering the Mediafailed event with:

```
Player.MediaPlayer.MediaFailed += mediaPlayer_MediaFailed;
```

...BUT it takes forever until it gets fired.

Is there a way to set the timeout for how long the player tries to open a stream?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample media source since I don't have a source that take much time to get failed.

Comment: Thanks. Eventually I wrapped it all into a task that times out after 9 seconds and produces a message for the user to choose another station.